# Special set in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: soft-question

Is there a name for sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ of the form
$$
(-\infty,r_1]\times(-\infty,r_2]\times\cdots\times(-\infty,r_d],
$$
where $r_1,\ldots,r_d$ are real numbers?

Comment: Half-open $d$-dimensional unbounded rectangles? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Half-Open_Rectangle except usually the half-open end is the upper end of each interval. Possibly "generalised quadrant" although in 3 dimensions it's an octant.

Comment: Product of half-infinite closed intervals?

Comment: A translated (shifted) orthant.